# Limit of Logistic Functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

[Here is the problem I am referring to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6ZN9.png) Part (d) of this problem initially seemed easy to me, but now I am doubting my answer. I figured out that L'Hopital's would be used after given the initial limit. At first I figured the L'Hopital's would simply lead to $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ky(M-y)}{ky(M-y)}$$ as both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ come from the same differential equation. From here I concluded that this limit would evaluate to 1.

However, upon looking at the problem again, I realized that this could not be correct. One issue I saw is that the $y$'s in the numerator and the $y$'s in the denominator are not the same, and should instead be written as $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ respectively. This would mean that the numerator and denominator are not necessarily equivalent, so I realized the limit may not evaluate to $1$ as I suspected.

Another issue I saw was a logical one. $g(x)$ will be approaching the carrying capacity of $10$ from the top, so as $x$ increases, $g(x)-10$ should be just greater than $0$. Conversely, I found that $f(x) - 10$ would be just under $0$ as $x$ increases. This lead me to believe that a positive answer should not be possible, as the denominator would always be negative, and the numerator would always be positive.

Finally, I found that if I continued using L'Hopital's, both the numerator and denominator would continue evaluating to $0$. So my current belief is that the limit does not exist, however after this lengthy thought process I am still unsure if this is the case. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.